# C# CodeDom "} Expected"

Tags: c#, codedom

I played a bit with CodeDom and got an error message.
The error message is

> } Expected!

I tried searching for the error but could not find anything of value.
Why do I get this error?

```
String InputCode = String.Empty;
InputCode = "MessageBox.Show((1 + 2 + 3).ToString());";

System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider CodeDomProvider = System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");

System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters CompilerParameters = new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters();
CompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
CompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");
CompilerParameters.CompilerOptions += "/target:winexe" + " " + "/win32icon:" + "\"" + textBox6.Text + "\"";
CompilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = true;

StringBuilder Temp = new StringBuilder();
Temp.AppendLine(@"using System;");
Temp.AppendLine(@"using System.Windows.Forms;");
Temp.AppendLine(@"namespace RunTimeCompiler{");
Temp.AppendLine(@"public class Test{");
Temp.AppendLine(@"public static void Main(){");
Temp.AppendLine(@"public void Ergebnis(){");

Temp.AppendLine(InputCode);
Temp.AppendLine(@"}}}}}");

System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults CompilerResults = CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParameters, Temp.ToString());
//Auf CompilerFehler prüfen
if (CompilerResults.Errors.Count > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show(CompilerResults.Errors[0].ErrorText, "Fehler bei Laufzeitkompilierung", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    return;
}
```

Comment: With the posted code `Ergebnis()` is declared inside `Main()`, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is incorrect. You have a method inside another method, which is not allowed. Therefore the compiler states it expects a `}`, before the `public void Ergebnis()`.

Your code if you write it out is

```
1. using System;
2. using System.Windows.Forms;
3. namespace RunTimeCompiler {
4. public class Test {
5.     public static void Main() {
6.        public void Ergebnis() {
7.            MessageBox.Show((1 + 2 + 3).ToString());
8.        }
9.     }
10.}
11.}
12.}
```

Note that on line 6 you need to close the method scope for Main before declaring your next method. A correct program would be

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace RunTimeCompiler {
public class Test {
    public static void Main() {
        new Test().Ergebnis();
    }
    public void Ergebnis() {
        MessageBox.Show((1 + 2 + 3).ToString());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

At the very end of the code you pasted, you're missing a close brace to your if statement, and it would also appear that the following line has one extra `}` in it:

```
Temp.AppendLine(@"}}}}}");
```

It looks like it should be:

```
Temp.AppendLine(@"}}}}");
```